# Adding string to child elements of div class

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

I have the following script, which is not doing what I want it to do:

```
<html>
<body>

<div class="test">
 <div class="one">sdas</div >
 <div class="two">adsa</div >
 <div class="three">sad</div >
 <div class="four">sada</div >
</div>
<br /><br /><br />
<div id="DIV2">
</div>

<p>Click the button to change the text of the first list item (index 0).</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>

function myFunction() {
    var MyDiv2 = document.getElementById('DIV2');
    var doc = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
    var str = 'str';

    for (var i = 0; i < doc.length; i++) {

        MyDiv2.innerHTML = doc[i].innerHTML + str;
    }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Once the button is pushed, it outputs this:

```
sdas 
adsa 
sad 
sada


sdas 
adsa 
sad 
sada 
str
```

However, I would like to have the following output:

```
sdas
adsa 
sad 
sada


sdas 
str 
adsa 
str 
sad 
str 
sada 
str
```

So for each child class, `str` should be added. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to change the `doc` variable selector using `querySelectorAll` like that:

```
function myFunction() {
    // ...
    var doc = document.querySelectorAll(".test span");
    var str = 'str';

    for (var i = 0; i < doc.length; i++) {
        MyDiv2.innerHTML += doc[i].innerHTML + ' ' + str + ' ';
    }
}
```

**Update**

You changed from `span` to `div`, so you can use `doc = document.querySelectorAll(".test div")` if you only want the `div`s.

To get all children in general, you can use `doc = document.querySelector(".test").children`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `querySlectorAll` & target the div and its child spans. In your code `doc[i].innerHTML` will give the child span elements, but the variable str is suppose to add to the textContent

```js
function myFunction() {
  // a new variable which will be concatenation of all the text
  var newString = '' 
  var MyDiv2 = document.getElementById('DIV2');
  var doc = document.querySelectorAll(".test span");
  var str = 'testString';
  for (var i = 0; i < doc.length; i++) {
   // trim is used to remove any white space
    newString += doc[i].textContent.trim() + str + ' ';
  }
  MyDiv2.innerHTML = newString


}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <span class="one">sdas</span>
  <span class="two">adsa</span>
  <span class="three">sad</span>
  <span class="four">sada</span>
</div>
<br /><br /><br />
<div id="DIV2">
</div>

<p>Click the button to change the text of the first list item (index 0).</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

Take a new variable i.e. output, push the results into this array while looping. Once done with loop, join the array. Please note that I am using id selector on `div` now.

```html
<body>

<div class="test" id="test">
 <div class="one">sdas</div >
 <div class="two">adsa</div >
 <div class="three">sad</div >
 <div class="four">sada</div >
</div>
<br /><br /><br />
<div id="DIV2">
</div>

<p>Click the button to change the text of the first list item (index 0).</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>

function myFunction() {
    var MyDiv2 = document.getElementById('DIV2');
    var items = document.getElementById("test").children;
    var str = 'str';
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        output.push(`${items[i].innerHTML} <br /> ${str} <br />`);
    }
    MyDiv2.innerHTML = output.join("");
}

</script>

</body>
```